# Use same colors for scatter and contourf on same plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, contour

I have to plot the decision boundaries of a classifier and the samples (with labels) used to train the classifier so I am using scatter plot and contourf. I can't find a way to use the same colors for both functions, when I specify a color sequence the scatter plot works well but the colors for the boundaries do not follow the order that I expect.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import sklearn.naive_bayes as nb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
clf = nb.GaussianNB() 
X = np.zeros((4, 2), dtype=int)
X[0, :] = 10
X[1, :] = 20
X[2, :] = 30
X[3, :] = 40
Y = [0, 1, 2, 3]
clf.fit(X, Y)
x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - 1, X[:, 0].max() + 1
y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min() - 1, X[:, 1].max() + 1
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, 0.1), np.arange(y_min, y_max,0.1))
Z = clf.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
colors_ = ['red', 'yellow', 'cyan', 'blue']
plt.contourf(xx, yy, Z, colors=colors_, alpha=0.5)
labels = ['dog', 'guitar', 'house', 'person']
for i in np.unique(Y):
    mask = Y == i
    plt.scatter(X[mask, 0], X[mask, 1], c=colors_[i], label=labels[i], 
edgecolors='k', alpha=0.8)
plt.legend()
plt.xlim(xx.min(), xx.max())
plt.ylim(yy.min(), yy.max())
plt.title('Decision Boundaries of Naive Bayes Classifier')
plt.show()
```

The image should have decision regions and scatter points with more or less the same colors (i.e. yellow region where most of the yellow points are, red region where most of the red points are and so on)....with the code above the colors are mixed (i.e. red region where most of the yellow points are).

I suppose that this is simply a problem about ordering but I can't figure it out.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't create a verifiable example because I am using a dataset which is not public. By the way X2T is simply a matrix with shape 1087x2 where 1087 is the number of samples and 2 is the number of features (extracted with PCA on first 2 principal components). The code is working correctly if I use the library mlxtend to plot the decision boundaries and the data automatically, it does not work when I do it manually so the problem is after the 6th line in the code above.

Comment: If your dataset isn't available to be made public, then use a different dataset that is already public

Comment: or better yet, remove the machine learning component entirely. it has nothing to do with the problem at hand: syncing up colors between `scatter` and `contourf`

Comment: this seems to be working fine for me. the dots appear slightly darker than the areas, but that's b/c they are both slightly transparent from your specified `alpha` values

Comment: I have updated the code with a simple version. This is not working correctly on my pc, I get a correct match only in case of blue point with blue decision boundary background color (same for red). But for the yellow point I get a cyan background and for the cyan point I get a red background...so the scatter plot uses 4 colors as expected but the boundaries only use 3 colors

Comment: this is what I obtain https://ibb.co/zs8z5HL

Comment: check your array. their might just be tiny slivers that you can't see at the resolution of the image. also, i do think that you should remove the machine learning component from the problem, since that has little to do with the plotting

Comment: the problem is not related to the array. using the mlxtend library with an automatic scatter + decision region plot I get this result https://ibb.co/SfgKY7L which is exactly what I expect to obtain.  as you can see the color of the region and the color of the point are always the same...this does not happen with the code I wrote in the first post.

Comment: so is it a problem with the plotting, or that the classifier isn't producing expected output?

Comment: it is a problem with the plotting, 100% sure about it....I think it's related to levels used by contourf function because it uses only 3 of the 4 available colors that I specify in the color sequence. unfortunately I have just started using python and I do not know anything about advanced matplotlib functions.